# Verify all keys within JSON Array using Python request

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I have JSON Array like this:

```
   data = """ [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "crm/index",
            "description": "CRM/Dashboard"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "crm/index/with_search",
            "description": "CRM/Global Search"
        }
    ]"""
```

Now, I have to verify that within this json three keys i.e. 'id', 'name' and 'description' are displaying throughout.

I have used following method:

```
student = json.loads(data)
if "id" in student:
   print("Key exist in JSON data")
else:
   print("Key doesn't exist in JSON data")
```

But it is returning me else statment, I need to know, where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `any()`:

```py
import json

data = """\
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "crm/index",
        "description": "CRM/Dashboard"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "crm/index/with_search",
        "description": "CRM/Global Search"
    }
]"""

data = json.loads(data)

if any("id" in dct for dct in data):
    print("Key exists in data")
else:
    print("Key doesn't exists in data")
```

Prints:

```
Key exists in data
```

---

If you want to check if key `id` exists in **all** dictionaries in `data`, use `all()` instead of `any()`

Comment: That's pretty cool, but can we use list of keys instead of passing individual names, like instead of 'id', can we verify it with ['id', 'name', 'description']

Comment: @TaimoorPasha You can try `if any(word in dct for dct in data for word in ["id", "name", "description"]):  ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import json


data = """ [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "crm/index",
        "description": "CRM/Dashboard"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "crm/index/with_search",
        "description": "CRM/Global Search"
    }
]"""
students = json.loads(data)
for student in students:
    if "id" in student:
        print("Key exist in JSON data")
    else:
        print("Key doesn't exist in JSON data")
```